# How to include the image description when the lightbox is open for gallerificPlus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, galleriffic

https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/gallerificPlus

I see that line 247 of gallerificPlus.js creates the divs & spans which add information to the lightbox.

I want to display a longer description for the image when the lightbox is opened.

I know I would likely have to add `<span id="lightbox-image-details-description"></span>` right after `<span id="lightbox-image-details-caption"></span>`. (line 247 of gallerificPLus.js)

But how would I get this new span to populate with the description?

I imagine that whatever steps were taken to populate content in  `<span id="lightbox-image-details-caption"></span>` need to repeated in a similar manner to populate a span that I think I would need to add `<span id="lightbox-image-details-caption"></span>` with the description.

Comment: Please include your relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: @Laurel all the code discussed is on https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/gallerificPlus

Comment: You cannot rely on links because they break (sometimes irreparably). The other thing is that I didn't realize there was any code at first because you failed to use code formatting and they all got stripped out (but I fixed that at least).

Comment: My apologies @Laurel. I should not have made the assumption that github link would not break. I appreciate you fixing the code formatting. I will be sure to use for next time. This is my first post so I appreciate your help! The js file is over 1000 lines, do you still suggest including all of it in the post?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing exactly (I'm not familiar with the technologies), but you probably aren't using all of those lines. If you're using it as a library, I would suggest setting something up as a Stack Snippet, (click the button in the toolbar when editing) so that we can run it. As a general guideline, include as little as possible, but enough to solve the problem.

Comment: This is a plugin. Being that I dont know what exactly needs to be changed, I wouldnt know what lines to include in my question. One would have to read my question and go to the github link. I did my best to keep the question as clear as I could. Again thank you for all your advice and help.

Comment: Your question is better than most of the questions that come in. :) The fact that you know how to write grammatical English helps too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in touch with the plugin author, he was able to make the necessary updates and updated the repository https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/gallerificPlus